# Why do some events just appear in the code?

Tags: c#, events

I noticed something weird , for the textbox  there are some events that just appear in the code, but in the design(when I open properties , and click on the events tab) these events are not visible !

for example :

```
textbox1.LostFocus += textbox1.LostFocus;
```

or the GotFocus event .

Anybody has an idea regard this ??

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because some events not Browsable

if you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will see `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]` for the events like GotFocus

if BrowsableAttribute  false then that event not displayed in a Properties window.

> **Note**   The GotFocus and LostFocus events are low-level focus events
>   that are tied to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS Windows messages.
>   Typically, the GotFocus and LostFocus events are only used when
>   updating UICues or when writing custom controls. **Instead the Enter and
>   Leave events should be used**  for all controls except the Form class,
>   which uses the Activated and Deactivate events.

Comment: @KaramNajjar read the documentation of [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx): `Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a Properties window.`

Answer (score 0):

In which method / function do you register (+= ) that events? Only the events registered in the InitializeComponent (DesignerCode) / constructor code, are considered by the Designer.

Edit: In that case, Damith is right with Browsable(false).

My answer would be valid if you see the event in the Designer, but not the linked event handler method.